# access.log requests from UA "Google favicon"...? What do these mean?

Tags: googlebot, nginx

I have a bunch of these in my nginx log file, on a range of URLs:

```
on 66.102.9.23 - - [12/Nov/2015:10:40:25 +0000] 
    "GET /myadminfolder/page.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1247 1800 
    "-" "Google favicon" "111.111.111.111"
```

Where 111.111.111.111 is my home IP address.

(Whatever it is isn't logged in so thankfully it gets bounced to the login page after this.)

I don't fully understand these, what they are or why they happen.  I looked the IP address up and it does appear to be google (http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#ipInformation|type=ipv4&&value=66.102.9.23).

My admin folder is "secret" and not linked anywhere (security through obscurity...).  That and my IP address suggest it must be something to do with my Chrome browser, I guess?

I've not accessed that page myself since 22 hours prior to this log though, so it's certainly not something that happens AS I browse.

Can someone tell me

1. what this is
2. WHY it is
3. if I should be worried about it!?

Thanks!